# I can not install my upload app via play store but my device is registered in supported devices

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, google-play-console

I've just uploaded my first app to the play store for WearOs, but when I try to install it on my Samsung galaxy watch 4 it says that I don't have any eligible device.

[image: Image from play console]

[image: image from play store]

This is the AndroidMaifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.senyor_o.pomodoro">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.senyor_o.pomodoro.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Why I can not install in my Wear OS device? Is there any problem in my app?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your phone (not your watch)

Your Xiaomi Poco X3

Comment: Why is the phone causing a problem if the app is just for wear OS devices?

Comment: Most probably because you have Android 10 and the watch needs the phone to be at least Android 11 to work

Answer (score 0):

You have not included those devices.

[image]

Click "Manage Devices" and include them.

Comment: I've included all the devices, now each one it's supported but I can not install it yet via play store. I have to do anything to see this changes on play store?